# Laravel 5.6 vuejs Project Deploy On Shared Hosting Without Using SSH Access

Tags: laravel, deployment, vue.js, laravel-5.6

I have taken a shared hosting which do not provide me SSH Access. So I have facing little problem regarding to Deployment of Laravel Vuejs project On hosting. I don't know how to do this please share your valuable suggestion to get rid of this....

Comment: Upload your vendor directory, export the database and import it. Whatever you automate, you'll need to do manually. There's no black magic going on

Comment: You can execute `artisan` commands without the console access. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands